# Can't seek audio files prepared with HTTP source (Android MediaPlayer)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-mediaplayer

So I'm trying to build some sort of a media player, the application prepares audio from an external source (HTTP server sitting on another device), when trying to seek the MediaPlayer returns "Stream has no duration and is therefore not seekable"

Note: I saw questions about the same error but they were about live streams, this is a static MP3 file.

Code from the other device (the server of the audio files)

```
private static void WriteFile(HttpListenerContext ctx, Android.Net.Uri uri, Activity activity)
        {
            var response = ctx.Response;
            Debug.Print(ctx.Request.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            using (var file = activity.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri))
            {
                string fileName = "Audio.mp3";
                ICursor cursor = activity.ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                try
                {
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.MoveToFirst())
                        fileName = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DisplayName));
                }
                finally
                {
                    cursor.Close();
                }
                response.SendChunked = false;
                response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
                response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[64 * 1024];
                int read;
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(response.OutputStream))
                {
                    while ((read = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        bw.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                        bw.Flush();
                    }
                    bw.Close();
                    response.ContentLength64 = bw.BaseStream.Length;
                }

                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                response.StatusDescription = "OK";
                response.OutputStream.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this code is not throwing a "cannot access a closed stream" exception:

```
bw.Close();
response.ContentLength64 = bw.BaseStream.Length;
```

But... retrieve the length before closing the stream:

```
response.ContentLength64 = bw.BaseStream.Length;
bw.Close();
```